# Synchronized method not threadsafe

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Can someone please let me know why is the below code not threadsafe ? The output I get is either 0 or 45 or 90. The shared resource counter has a synchronized method, so I am expecting 90 as the output all the times. Am I missing something here ? Please advise.
Kindly, also let me know how to make this code threadsafe.

```
class Counter{

    long count = 0;

    public synchronized void add(long value){
      this.count += value;
    }
 }
 class CounterThread extends Thread{

    protected Counter counter = null;

    public CounterThread(Counter counter){
       this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
          counter.add(i);
       }
    }
 }
 public class Example {

   public static void main(String[] args){

     Counter counter = new Counter();
     Thread  threadA = new CounterThread(counter);
     Thread  threadB = new CounterThread(counter);

     threadA.start();
     threadB.start();

     System.out.println(counter.count);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

wait for threads to finish. Add

```
threadA.join();
threadB.join();
```

before printing the result.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially you are reading the values before the two threads have completed their execution.

You can use a [join](http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2007/05/when-to-join-threads.html) to wait for the threads to finish.

Also try using [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) 's `addAndGet` method instead of the synchronized add method.

Answer (score 3):

You do not wait with the println until the threads have stopped. So you print out the value of the counter while the for-loops are still in process. It does not have to do anything with thread-safety.

Comment: Read about visibility http://jeremymanson.blogspot.nl/2007/08/atomicity-visibility-and-ordering.html. Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @Eugen: Hm, probably you are right. Making count volatile should help as well (with visibility, not with the original question), shouldn't it?

Comment: I tried making the variable volatile, it does not work. The output again can be 0 or 45 or 90. Thread.join seems to be a perfect solution.

Comment: Volatile, of course, does not solve your issue. You should, however, make count volatile in addition, for the reason pointed out by Eugen.

Answer (score 2):

`Counter` access is threadsafe, but `System.out.println(counter.count);` can happen before other threads do their work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is thread safe but a better way is get rid of synchronized method and use [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html)
And Use getAndAdd(long) method

```
public final long getAndAdd(long delta)
>Atomically add the given value to current value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 threads running there. The one assigned to variable `threadA`, the one assigned to `threadB` and the main thread.

The main thread runs as long as the `main` method runs. The other 2 are started and run concurrently with the main thread. However, the main thread is not blocked waiting for the other 2 to finish, so it prints the result when it gets a chance to execute.

Comment: I tried sleeping the main thread & I got the output as 90. The fact that there are 3 threads here, was causing the confusion.